# Copy data from last row of master sheet and paste it in specific cells in another sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy data from the last row of my master sheet which populates using a google form and paste it into a new sheet that is created when a form is submitted.
Now, I want the new sheet to automatically put certain text in specific cells and copy data from the last row in some specific cells.
Example-:
[The master sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iL3T.png)

now i want to copy the data in cell b2 (assuming 2 is the last row) to newly created sheet in the cell b1
from cell c2 to b3
from cell d2 to b4
from cell AL2 to h20 and so on.
I am new to google appscript.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From my understanding, you try to get the last line in your first sheet and put it as column in the second ? Or maybe I understand it wrongly ?

Comment: I put text data in a column and other data in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't what you meant by and so on.  But here's the instructions that you specified so far.

```
function copyMasterToNewSheet()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('The Master Sheet');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var row=rngA[rngA.length-1];
  var newsht=ss.insertSheet(row[0]);//It's name is the TimeStamp
  newsht.getRange('B1').setValue(row[1]);
  newsht.getRange('B3').setValue(row[2]);
  newsht.getRange('B4').setValue(row[3]);
  newsht.getRange('H20').setValue(row[37]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

You would need to hook this up to the on Form Submit trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. And "and so on" means that there are numerous other cells that i want to copy but an example of these four values will get me going.
I have already created a new sheet using the following code it is just getting values from specific cells and pasting it in specific cells in the new sheet that I need help with. 
`function myFunction() 
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var colB_Data = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue(); ss.insertSheet(colB_Data); };`